# Cascading Select elements with Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, html-select

I have a wizard view in my application that walks the user through a short series of screens that ultimately create a mock sale for testing/demo purposes. When the user selects a venue from a drop-down box, I want to render another drop-down with the deals for that venue.

However, when I try this the 'deal' drop-down is always empty. Thinking it might be a render() issue, I put in code to display the number of deals when the venue is selected and that works just fine.

MockSaleView.html

```
<select id="venue-select" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true"></select><br/>
<select id="deal-select" class="selectpicker"></select><br/>
<div id ="deal-count"></div>
```

MockSaleView.js

```
window.MockSaleView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function () {
        this.render();
    },

    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(this.template());

        for (var i = 0; i < venues_collection.length; i++) {
            $('#venue-select', this.el).append('<option value="'+venues_collection.models[i].toJSON()._id+'">'+venues_collection.models[i].toJSON().name+'</option>');
        }

        // Events
        $('#venue-select', this.el).on("change", this.venueSelectionChanged);
        $('#deal-select', this.el).on("change", this.dealSelectionChanged);

        return this;
    },

venueSelectionChanged: function(e){

    var field = $(e.currentTarget);
    var venue_id = $("option:selected", field).val();

    var _deals = deals_collection.where({venue: venue_id});
    $('#deal-count').html(deals.length+' deals');

    var dropdown = new DropdownView({
        el: $('#deal-select'),

        model: new Backbone.Model({
          deals: _deals
        })
    });
    dropdown.render();
},

});
```

**UPDATE #1:**

updated venueSelectionChanged() to utilize a DropdownView which creates a  widget based on a collection. I can see in the code where the HTML is created correctly, but it does not render. When I tested the View in the render() function of MockSaleView and was able to pass in this.el for MockSaleView it would render properly. Sorry, I am still new to development with Backbone.

Comment: Where do you get the values for your deals collection? Are they manually populated or coming from a REST service?

Comment: How about a functional demo on jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com? There's probably something going on in the code we can't see. Also, why are you doing `$('#venue-select', this.el).on("change", ...)` rather than using the view's `events`? And why `$('#venue-select', this.el)` rather than the more idiomatic `this.$('#venue-select')`?

Comment: @eggward the collections are populated via a REST service and the deals-count gets populated appropriately when a venue is selected (e.g. "3 deals" or "0 deals"). In other words, the deals_collection and where() seem to work fine too. I just can't get the darn drop-down to contain any options.

Comment: @mu I'll try to get something functional out on jsfiddle. I tried setting up events on the view, but they never got triggered. Maybe I wasn't doing it correctly.

Comment: I suspect `#deal-select` _not_ to be available in the DOM (`$('#deal-select') = []`) at the time of appending the new options (`$('#deal-select').append(...`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am using the bootstrap-selector plug-in, it does a render of the Select options, therefore it is necessary to call refresh after updating the values.

```
$('#deal-select').selectpicker('refresh');
```